# как протестить event.currentTarget.innerHTML?

Tags: reactjs, jest

```
//как добратся до innerHTML?
const handler = jest.fn()

await userEvent.click(divisionButton);
//в таком виде ошибка, так как event имеет множество других полей
expect(handler).toBeCalledWith({ currentTarget: { innerHTML: '/' } });

//пришел к этому варианту, но что то много лишних действий
let res = '';
  const handler = jest.fn().mockImplementation((e) => {
    res = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
  });

await userEvent.click(divisionButton);
  expect(res).toBe('/');
```